# Why line of code isn't executed after awaiting server response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server, async-await, httpresponse

In a react component I havel the following code:

```
const handleButton = async () => {
 
  const resp = await updateProject(projectInfo);
  setIsProjectModalVisible(false)

};
```

updateProject() is a POST request to a server and setIsProjectModalVisible is a setState function from the parent component that was passed as a prop.

I was having a strange behavior: with the previous code, the Modal wouldn't be hidden (setIsProjetModalVisible(false) wouldn't run), but if I swapped the two lines:

```
const handleButton = async () => {
 
  setIsProjectModalVisible(false)
  const resp = await updateProject(projectInfo);

};
```

it would work as expected and the Modal would become invisible.

After a bit of research, I identified the problem: the server wasn't responding to updateProject(). Fixing that, the second line of code would now result in the expected behavior.

Even though the problem is solved, I'd like to understand that behavior: since the server wasn't responding, I might expect an infinite wait in the await line, but while debugging, it would just skip that line and no error was shown. Why is that? Thanks!

Comment: I think from your code snippet its better to have a try catch, so in that case if the post thrown an error you could log at catch, I think error was occurring but from the code snippet there was nothing to catch it

Comment: turn off your server, try to run `updateProject(projectInfo).then(undefined, (reason) => console.log(reason));` instead of your await and post the result, please.

Comment: You would need to check if the promise was being fulfilled successfully or left pending. So it was probably not strictly an error but just your promise remaining unfulfilled/pending, leaving your code frozen. I think a catch would be good to catch actual errors, but wouldnt help with this particular async issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `updateProject`, it returns a Pending Promise. At first a pending promise wouldn't block the next following code `setIsProjectModalVisible(false)`.

But when you declare your function as `async`, and mark `await` to your promise you are stating that following code should only execute when your promise resolves. If the promise hangs on pending your code is blocked until the promise resolves.

The promise could also rejects (you get a server timeout error or something else goes wrong), which would throw an error, but your code wouldn't be executed. Your app would crash, unless you had wrapped your promise in a try/catch block (which is recommended), where you would handle the error at the catch block properly.

```
const handleButton = async () => {
  try {
    const resp = await updateProject(projectInfo);
    // if it rejects following code doesn't execute. jumps to catch block
    setIsProjectModalVisible(false)
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error here
    console.log(error)
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how your `updateProject` is written, when a POST request inside it fails in some way, it probably does not resolve (i.e. you don't catch the error) and thus your `const resp = await updateProject(projectInfo);` never actually gets anything back. That, of course, results in this part `setIsProjectModalVisible(false)` never being reached. Hence your modal does not disappear.

So that should explain the behavior. As for fixing it, well, just catch the error and still resolve the function. So something like this would work:

```
const updateProject = (project_data) => {
   return axios.post('url', project_data)
    .catch(e => {
       console.log(e);
       return "Error occurred";
    })
}
```

This way even when your post request bombs, your await will still get something back and won't stop the code from contunuing to execute.